# Android webview and https

Tags: android, webview

I have a question. I have application for 3.0 api. I am using webview to show page. I have a question if webview correctly use https? I want to create shop and I want to use https. If are any problems with that protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be alright, but if you don't have a certificate from a trusted authority you will need to somehow handle this.

The following snipped of code

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewId);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, 
        SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed() ;
    }
}
```

will display a dialog to the user, verifying if they trust your site and wish to continue or not.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using HTTPS with webviews for one of our applications with no problems. We process payments through it, so you're safe to use it.

Just make sure you're using a certificate from a trusted authority so you don't need any hacks.